# Store Emoticons in MYSQL - Out of range value for column

Tags: c#, mysql

i wants to stored the following Emoticons in mysql

```
   Emoticons                  Score    

    %-(          ,            -1
    %-)          ,             1
    (-:          ,             1
    :*(          ,            -1
```

This is comma separated file.
i write the following code to stroe this file

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\EmoticonLookupTable.txt");
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var data = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, 2);
                string  Emoticons  = data[0].Trim();
                int Score  = int.Parse(data[1].Trim());

                StoreRecord( Emoticons,Score);
            }
        }     

private void StoreRecord(string word,int Score)
        {
            var conStr = "server=localhost; database=zahid; password=zia; User Id=root;";
            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(conStr))
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.CommandText =
                @"INSERT INTO za 
            (Emoticons,Score) 
          VALUES 
            (@Emoticons,@Score)";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emoticons", Emoticons);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", Score);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

but this code gives the following error.
**Error**
Out of range value for column 'Score' at row 1
thanks in advace...

Comment: What is the datatype for Score column in your database table?

Comment: make sure score is signed data type.

Comment: What is your MySQL Table structure?  Please show us your `DESCRIBE TABLE za` output.

Comment: @rocky: Sir some Emoticons store in database but some are not store like x3?..

Comment: SQL Server Express is so easy to use with Visual Studio... I don't understand why people use MySQL with .NET in small applications.

Comment: @ZiaRehman: I'm sorry I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You probably trying to store negative number in `unsigned int` column in database.**

Your code is OK (`int` data type is signed integer, so it supports negative number), but you can have unsigned integer somewhere.

Other reason may be too big number.

MSDN says:

> Integer variables are stored as signed 32-bit (4-byte) integers
>   ranging in value from -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647.